# Lua Syntax error... "=" expected near "end"

Tags: lua, syntax-error

```
if paddle_2_y < 0 then
   paddle_2_y = 0
elseif (paddle_2_y + paddle_2_height) > screen_height then
   paddle_2_y = screen_height - paddle_2 _height
end
```

end

Cant seem to figure out the problem. Yes, I am new to scripting so this is probably easy to figure out.

Comment: `paddle_2 _height`, perhaps you mean `paddle_2_height`

Comment: Oh, spelling. Oops. Thanks!

Comment: please delete your question. it's of no value to anyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in a variable name (paddle_2 height).  Remove it and it will work.